# Libre Office Writer display small and narrow

Tags: files, libreoffice, resize

[image]
My Writer shows in this format, I want to make it the default - with bigger width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Change the zoom level of the document

Somehow you have made the scale of the document 39%. Move the slider at the bottom right corner of LibreOffice Writer to 100% or more.

See the image below:

[image]

You can change the zoom level also by holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and turning the scroll-wheel of the mouse.

[image]

If you don't have a mouse with scroll-wheel, but a touch-pad as in a laptop, you can hold down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and do the [touch-pad equivalent for scrolling](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHjJu5owfAw).

Also see [this question in Ask LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/136433/how-can-i-set-zoom-default/), and [another answer](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/28590/how-can-i-set-zoom-default/). Thanks to [pbhj](https://askubuntu.com/users/29073/pbhj) for pointing out the second one.

Hope it helps

Comment: You can do ctrl+scrollwheel to zoom as well, scrolling up zooms in. This [info](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/28590/how-can-i-set-zoom-default/) about changing default zoom might help.

Comment: @pbhj Thanks! I will incorporate your comments to my answer.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I didn't notice that